# Force of attraction on the actuator arm

Tags: dc-motor, electric-machine

> 1. An actuator system is shown below. All dimensions are in centimeters. The magnetic material is cast steel, whose magnetization characteristic is shown in Fig. 1.7. The magnetic core and air gap have a square cross-sectional area of 25cm2. The coil has 500 turns and 4:0 ohms resistance.
>    [image]
>
> a) The gap is d=1mm.
>
> (i) Determine the coil current and supply voltage (dc) required to establish an air gap flux density of 0.5 tesla.
>
> (ii) Determine the inductance of the coil.
>
> b) With the gap d=0.5mm
>
> (i) Determine the force of attraction on the actuator arm. Consider the same current found before in a(i).

I was doing this problem and I had no problems on solving the first two questions. But when the gap was reduced I couldn't figure it out. Hope someone could help me.

The first two questions:

a)(i)
$$Ni = H_{c} \times l_{c} + H_{g} \times g$$
By the graph:
$$H_{c} = 350 at/m$$
$$H_{g} = \frac{0.5}{\mu_{o}} = 397.88 \cdot 10^3$$
$$i = \frac{350 \times 0.6 + 397.88 \cdot 10^3 \times 1 \cdot 10^{-3}}{500} = 1.215 A$$

(ii)
$$L=\frac{N \times \phi}{i} \longrightarrow L=\frac{N \times B \times A}{i}$$
$$L=\frac{500 \times 0.5 \times 25 \cdot 10^{-4}}{1.215} = 0.514 H$$

Comment: Please, would be so kind as to include your solution process for the first two questions?

Comment: This should be in the book.  If it's electronic, search on "force", and maybe "coenergy" (if your book uses the same terms as mine did, 40 years ago).

Comment: I included my solution to the first two questions. @jonk

Comment: @TimWescott it's the same terms. But the thing is that  when the gap reduces I am not sure on how to find the new $$H_{c}$$ and new  $$H_{g}$$. Because one depends on the other by the solution I developed for the first question. I thought about considering the Hc constant, but I am not sure.

Comment: @Luz0000 I'll try and write something.

Comment: @jonk thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The force is somewhat non trivial because the force is due to the incremental change of inductance \$L\$ over an incremental change in position \$x\$ (i am calling the distance \$x\$ instead of \$d\$ for clarity). Let me derive it below. Someone else can see if they agree with this answer.

First perform a power balance between mechanical power and electrical power.
\begin{equation}
P_m=\frac{Fx}{t}\\
P_e=vi\\
P_m=P_e=\frac{Fx}{t}=vi
\end{equation}
Next apply faradays law. The total magnetic flux \$\lambda\$ is a function of the inductance. The inductance is a function of the distance from the core.
\begin{equation}
v=\frac{d\lambda}{dt}\\
\lambda = L(x)i
\end{equation}
Now put it all together
\begin{equation}
P_m=P_e=\frac{Fx}{t}=i\frac{d\lambda}{dt}\\
\frac{Fx}{t}=i^2\frac{d(L(x))}{dt}
\end{equation}
Break down the derivative into partials.
\begin{equation}
\frac{Fx}{t}=i^2\frac{d(L(x))}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt}
\end{equation}
Finally canceling out the velocity term \$\frac{x}{t}\$ gives you the following relationship.
\begin{equation}
F=i^2\frac{d(L(x))}{dx}
\end{equation}

Now look at the units to make sure they work out to be in Newtons
\begin{equation}
kg*m*s^2=(A^2)(kg*m^2*s^{−2}*A^{−2})(m^{-1})
\end{equation}

So all you need to do is take the derivative of the inductance with respect to position (just for air gap element) then plug in current.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but won't the $$H_c$$ change when the gap is reduced? $$Ni = H_{c} \times l_{c} + H_{g} \times g$$ by this equation, if g changes and $$N$$ and $$i$$ does not, then $$H_c$$ and $$H_g$$ will be different, or am I missing something?

Comment: I did take the derivative of the inductance and it is: $$\frac{d(L(x))}{dx} = \frac{N^2 \times A \times \mu_{c}^2 \times \mu_o}{(L_c \times \mu_o +x \times \mu_c)^2}$$ By this equation the force would depende on $$ \mu_{c} $$ which depends on the $$H_c$$. And if it changes when x is reduced, how can I find the force?